# Unable to play Multi-player on my 2nd Generation Kindle Fire with the new update v0.11.1 alpha

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My kids and I each have a paid Minecraft PE on our devices. I have a 2nd generation Kindle Fire and my kids each have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10. In the past I've been able to join in their worlds. They have never been able to join in any world I've created on my Kindle Fire. After some research, we found out that the 2nd generation Kindle has the program 'Kindle FreeTime', which apparently causes some conflict. But, I have always been able to join THEIR worlds created on the Samsung's.
Since the update (v0.11.1), I have not been able to join any of their worlds. We are all on the same wi-fi. We all have a paid version of the Pocket Edition. We all have our settings to accept Multi-player. When I go to join one of their worlds, my 2nd generation Kindle Fire displays 'Invalid Name'. 
Any help would be most appreciated. It's the one video game I actually enjoy playing with the kids. ;)
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my sisters kindle, and it took me a while to figure it out. Tell your kids to make sure they have no spaces in their gamer tag. So instead of putting " Big Boy" put " BigBoy". This fixed my sisters problem. Mom of 2